# Shell script for MultiThreaded File Processing

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, unix

I have a file which has 10-20 records. I need to call a process over these records. Can someone help me write some multithreaded shell script for it?

Comment: your request lacks a bit of info on what is it you're trying to execute in parallel; mind adding some example to your post?

Answer (score 1):

In a general execution, you may use `xargs`:

```
cat file | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'your_script.sh {}'
```

Having `{}` as an argument being given to `your_script.sh`, and `-n 1` determining the number of lines to be passed as arguments to your script.

For example:

```
$ cat > file
a
b 
c

$ cat > t.sh
echo [ $1 ];

$ cat file | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c './t.sh {}'
[ a ]
[ b ]
[ c ]
```